# Transparent circle in white rectangle using fireworks

Tags: transparency, adobe-fireworks

I need to make a transparent circle in a white rectangle/background... so using css I can can color the transparent area and obtain a colored circle. Help!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to set `Blend mode` of the circle to `Erase`.

[image]

The other way would be to `Punch Paths` (on `Path` panel).